# ConfigurationException in Java?

Tags: java, apache-commons

Decided to use Apache's Common Configuration package to parse an XML File.

I decided to do a:

```
XMLConfiguration xmlConfig = new XMLConfiguration(file);
```

To which Eclipse complained that I haven't caught an exception(`Unhandled exception type ConfigurationException`), so I hit the trusty `surround with try/catch` and it added the following code:

```
try 
    {
        XMLConfiguration xmlConfig = new XMLConfiguration(file);
    } 
    catch (ConfigurationException ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However now it's complaining:

```
No exception of type ConfigurationException can be thrown; an exception type 
must be a subclass of Throwable
```

I don't understand why it's gave me that error when Eclipse is the one that suggested to add it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException` extends `org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableException`.

Do you have Commons Lang on your path also? If not, Eclipse will fail to resolve the `ConfigurationException` class, and you'll get that error.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/Predicate`. Do you know why this is? So confused. I added it to my libraries in Eclipse!

Comment: @8EM: Looks like you need Commons Collections also.

Comment: you may still get errors if you're not careful with the version dependencies on this.... check here for more info:http://stackoverflow.com/a/7651867/26510

Comment: For cases where more than one jar is needed for an import, how does one track down which jars are required?  thanks for the tip on commons lang.

Answer (score 20):

You need [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi) **2.6**

(Current release of Apache Common Configuration (1.8) wont works with version 3.1 of Apache Common Lang library, you might need to check Common configuration dependencies [here](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/dependencies.html) )

Answer (score 8):

I also faced this problem.
To fix this - Please download commons-lang-2.6.jar from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi
and add this commons-lang-2.6.jar to your project's build path. this should solve your problem.