# Fail ANT Build On Missing Dependencies

Tags: java, ant

I have come across the same issue as this [Proper usage of Apache Commons Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651799/proper-usage-of-apache-commons-configuration) i.e. Commons Lang is not included as a dependency.

Although eclipse and IDEA both pick it up, javac from ANT does not.

```
<javac debug="true" destdir="${build.classes.dir}" srcdir="${src.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
  <classpath refid="build.classpath"/>
</javac>
```

I want the build server to be able to pick up these dependency issues and fail the build if someone has missed them out.

Comment: You mean the build actually compiles without the required dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Suresh Koya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13277516/368630) is close, but there's a couple of issues:

- Suresh's way will only work if `commons-lang.jar` is actually in the current directory.
- It also won't work if the jar is called something like `commons-lang-2.6.jar`.

The first can be fixed by adding a `<filepath>` sub-entity to `<available>`. This gives the `<available>` condition a directory path to search for the jar. However, it won't work if the user downloaded `commons-lang` with the version number on it (as you would from a Maven repository).

To get around this issue, you need to create a path resource using something like `<fileset>` and then checking to see if you picked up any version of the commons-lang jarfile. You can see below that I am looking for any file that begins with `commons-lang` and has a `.jar` suffix.

After I set my resource, I can use a `<resoucecount>` condition to see if I picked up any version of `commons-lang`:

```
<path id="commons-lang.path">
     <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
         <incude name="commons-lang*.jar"/>
     </fileset>
</path>

<fail message="Missing commons-lang Jar">
    <condition>
        <resourcecount refid="commons-lang.path" 
             when="equals" count="0"/>
    </condition>
```

Now, if I know something about the commons-lang jar, I could have used the `<available>` condition to search for a particular class in my classpath:

```
<fail message="Can't find commons-lang Jar">
     <condition>
         <not>
            <available classname="org.apache.commons.lang.Entities">
                 <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
            </available>
         </not>
     </condition>
</fail>
```

This will find that commons-lang jar no matter what it's called.

If you're interested in Ivy, I have a project in [GitHub](https://github.com/qazwart/ivy.dir) that makes it pretty easy to add Ivy to an entire development site. Third party dependency management is the way to go. Using Ivy is great because it integrates with Ant. Maven and Gradle have their advantages, but you'll have to redo your whole build infrastructure in order to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Add a task as below

```
<fail  message="Missing the commons lang jar dependency.">
  <condition>
     <not>  
     <available file="common-lang.jar"/>
     </not>
  </condition>
</fail>
```

Ant fail task link: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage your builds 3rd party dependencies.

```
<ivy:cachepath pathid="build.classpath">
    <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.6" conf="default"/>
</ivy:cachepath>
```

By default [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) will download (and cache) from the Maven Central repository and is aware of transitive dependencies (dependencies of dependencies).