# No exception of type DataAccessException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable

Tags: exception

My source code like below.
It has a error, "No exception of type DataAccessException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable".

I can't understand why the error ocurrs.
let me know. thx.

```
package com.sds.afi.cosmos.cmm.db.impl;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.ibatis.support.SqlMapClientDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.sds.afi.cosmos.cmm.db.MainDao;

@Repository
//@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")   // 부적절한 컴파일러의 경고를 제거
public class MainDaoImpl extends SqlMapClientDaoSupport  implements MainDao {

    @Autowired
    private SqlMapClientTemplate sqlMapClientTemplate;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<HashMap> getUserInfo() throws DataAccessException {

        List<HashMap> lists;

        lists = sqlMapClientTemplate.queryForList("common.getList");

        return lists;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 23):

This can happen if some class in the type-hierarchy of the exception is not on the class-path. In that case, its not possible to verify whether the exception really extends Throwable, whether it is a checked one or not, etc. Hence the errors. e.g superclass of Dataaccessexception : NestedRuntimeException may be missing from the class-path as it is in a differnt jar i.e. spring-core.

Answer (score 2):

Your DataAccessException is not a subclass of Throwable class (extends Throwable). It should be, and without this inheritance, your code is not compilable with the current throws clause. 
Here is an example: http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=754

Comment: I wonder the difference between a class that extends Throwable and a subclass of subclass. And If that exception that error occurs is not a subclass of Throwable, How can I handle this problem?

Comment: I chased my DataAccessException's super classes. And it extends Java.lang.Excpetion.

Comment: That's odd. According to this thread (first answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416980/configurationexception-in-java, if the superclass is missing from the classpath, you may get this exception.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when I upgraded to 5.X.X version. I have added Spring-core.jar file and it worked fine for me. Just adding this here because it may help some one. Spring txn jar , dao jar and spring core are must.

Answer (score 0):

This means that in your `getUserInfo()` method there is no code that throws that exception. So just remove the `throws` clause from your method declaration.

Comment: If I get rid of it, another error "Unhandled exception type DataAccessException" occured.

Comment: then, I wrapped it with try~ catch statements. but another error "No exception of type DataAccessException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable" ouccred.

Comment: I think the other answer is probably what you are looking for then, make sure that your DataAccessException is the same one in the called method as in the calling method.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem.
What I have done wrong was I have created Exception class(by mistake) of my own.
In other programs I was trying to extend Exception class(default) but complier(eclipse)was loading user defined Exception class giving me same error.
So please make sure you are not overriding any default class.