# PartInitException in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to open an internal browser while developing a plugin for eclipse.
I have used the plugin template `Hello, world command`. and I am stuck to this error saying

`No exception of type PartInitException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable`

here is my code snippet:

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    IWebBrowser browser;
    try {           
        browser = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport().createBrowser("my browser");            
    } catch (PartInitException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    browser.openURL(new URL("http://www.google.com"));
    return null;

}
```

Comment: you need to handle exception thrown by openURL() which throws PartInitException. The throws in method `execute` doesn't handle this.

Comment: is there any extra library i have to include to fix this error

Comment: OK. Think I got it now. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379207/no-exception-of-type-dataaccessexception-can-be-thrown-an-exception-type-must-b

Comment: here is the screenshot http://imgur.com/CqEZNX2

Comment: Yep. Have a look at the link I added and my new answer

Answer (score 3):

Answer of shlomi33 is OK for me.
Here is the procedure to fix the problem:
a) Double click on MANIFEST.MF file of the project that is not compiling
b) Click on the "Dependencies" tab
c) Click on the "Add.." button to add a Required Plugin
d) Type "org.eclipse.core.runtime", select it on the list, click "OK" button

Repeat eventually c) and d) with "org.eclipse.swt", "org.eclipse.ui","org.eclipse.ui.ide"

Comment: I don't believe that `org.eclipse.swt` or `org.eclipse.ui.ide` is needed for exception type `PartInitException`.

Answer (score 1):

Your PartInitException is not in the classpath hence the compiler can not determine if it is an exception and of what kind.

Have a look here as well for a similar problem: 
[No exception of type DataAccessException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379207/no-exception-of-type-dataaccessexception-can-be-thrown-an-exception-type-must-b)

Comment: I tried putting that too in try catch block but still the error is No exception of type PartInitException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable

Comment: Please have a look at my comment and the re-constructed answer I posted

Comment: how do i Add it to its class path, I tried going to project properties->java build path. but what next ? I am new to this eclipse plugin development

Comment: mmm... I have no plug-ins env set up right now so I am afraid that I will not be able help here. I suggest that you ask a dedicated question asking just that.